# Why is the error' ValueError at /add_to_cart/printed-shirt/ Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Red'.' being thrown?

Tags: python, django

I got this error and have no idea why this is coming

> ValueError at /add_to_cart/printed-shirt/
>
> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Green'.

I'm trying to add variations to my product. So when I'm submitting, I'm printing the values the users are selecting by writing `print(request.POST.getlist('variations', []))` and those are coming back as `['Red', 'Medium']`.
Now I was trying to see if the product matching these variations already exists in the cart. If it exists, then I would increase the quantity, and if it does not exist, then I would add a new item. The error is being thrown at the line

> order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(

But my code doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    variations = request.POST.getlist('variations', [])
    print(variations)

    minimum_variation_count = Variation.objects.filter(item=item).count()
    if len(variations) < minimum_variation_count:
        messages.info(request, "Please specify the required variations.")


    order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user= request.user,
        ordered=False,
    )

    for v in variations:
        order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
            item_variations__exact=v
        )

    if order_item_qs.exists():
        order_item = order_item_qs.first()
        order_item.quantity += 1
        order_item.save()
    else:
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            item=item,
            user= request.user,
            ordered=False,
        )

        order_item.item_variations.add(*variations)
        order_item.save()

    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
            order.items.add(order_item) 
            messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
            return redirect("order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
        return redirect("order-summary")
    return redirect("order-summary")
```

My models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   price = models.FloatField()

class Variation(models.Model):
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50) # size, color

class ItemVariation(models.Model):
   variation  = models.ForeignKey(Variation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   value = models.CharField(max_length=50) # small, medium large etc

class OrderItem(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   item  = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   item_variations = models.ManyToManyField(ItemVariation)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
   ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Order(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
   start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
   ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

My order_summary.html (where I can increase quantity):

```
<a href="{% url 'remove-single-item-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}" class="btn mr-2"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
{{ order_item.quantity }}<a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug %}" class="btn ml-2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

My urls.py:

```
path('add_to_cart/<slug>/', orders_views.add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
path('remove_from_cart/<slug>/', orders_views.remove_from_cart, name='remove-from-cart'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without more information, so I'll ask some extra things:

1. What Line is throwing the error?
2. <s>What is slug's value when the error is thrown?</s> (didn't see url posted up top)
3. <s>What is OrderItem model</s>

**Original Answer:**

That being said, I think the error is this line: `order_item.item_variations.add(*variations)`.
variations is, I believe, `['Green', ...]`. I feel like it probably would be something like `order_item.item_variations.add(item.variation_set.filter(item_variation__value=...).first().pk)` with the current model setup. The reason I think this is because it doesn't look the value of ItemVariation is the primary_key which is what add takes as arguments (or instances)

**Extra Explanation:**

First, I think your check to see if the item is already in the cart is wrong:

```
order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
            item_variations__exact=v
        )
```

should be:

```
order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
            item_variations__value=v
        )
```

I changed it to check for the value which is where you'll find the strings you are comparing. The previous was checking id, I believe. I also removed `__exact`, but realize that `__exact` is implied in the fixed version.

Secondly, I believe that you are using `.add()`^ wrong for your `RelatedManager` (how you access your many-to-many field). According to your models, `ItemVariation` does not have a primary key set in the model. This means django will autogenerate one for you.^^ The auto-generated field will be an AutoField that is an int. This means in order to use `OrderItem.item_variations.add()` you either need to provide an ItemVariation instance or a primary key of ItemVariation.

Currently you are providing it with a bunch of strings. To fix this you will need to query ItemVariations to get the correct instance. I would recommend changing `order_item.item_variations.add(*variations)` to a multi-line approach:

```
item_variations_to_add = ItemVariations.objects.filter(
    variation__item=item,
    value__in=variations
).values_list('id', flat=True)
order_item.item_variations.add(*item_variations_to_add)
```

This should fix the error, though it does present a potential problem of what if the variations aren't in the database. That is another problem you should think about, but is outside the scope of this answer.

^`RelatedManager.add()` documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

^^Automatic Primary Keys documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: With the extra information, I still stand behind the assumption my answer made. A ValueError is being thrown because 'Green' is not of the same type of ItemVariation's primary key which is autogenerated as id. You need to provide the primary keys (or instances) to the manyToMany manager's add method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a noob, and didn't understand completely.....

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could show the way

Comment: Working on expanding answer. I'll comment again when done!

Comment: Thank you a ton!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! What a genius mann, I'm left shocked..... Thank you once again mate, for helping me....

Comment: Bro are you there? Now I'm facing another problem with the code, a bug to be more specific, that is when I'm adding an item to the cart for the first time(with variations let's say Red and Medium), it's being added nicely. Then when I'm adding another item(let's say Blue and Large), it's also working. But when, I'm increasing the item quantity from the order_summary.html, it's increasing the quantity of the other item not the one I clicked(if I clicked Red and Medium, Blue and Large's quantity is increased) and says : *Please specify the required variations.* I'll include my order_summary.html

Comment: Your order_summary only passes the item to the view. You need to pass variations in the POST data in order for your view to filter to the correct OrderItem. Otherwise it just grabs the first one it finds. Also, you are using a GET request (retrieving data) with your HTML even though it looks like you want a POST request (modifying data). You need to have your link send a POST request with 'variations' list within the data.

Comment: Can you please show me the way to fix this? I would be grateful to you....